# Can't assign to struct variable

Tags: go

I've got a map

```
var users = make(map[int]User)
```

I'm filling the map and all is fine.  Later, I want to assign to one of the values of User, but I get an error.

```
type User struct {
  Id int
  Connected bool
}

users[id].Connected = true   // Error
```

I've also tried to write a function that assigns to it, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: what typo? I can't see it :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

type User struct {
    Id        int
    Connected bool
}

func main() {
    users := make(map[int]User)
    id := 42
    user := User{id, false}
    users[id] = user
    fmt.Println(users)

    user = users[id]
    user.Connected = true
    users[id] = user
    fmt.Println(users)
}
```

Output:

```
map[42:{42 false}]
map[42:{42 true}]
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case it is helpful to store pointers in the map instead of a structure:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type User struct {
        Id        int
        Connected bool
}

func main() {
        key := 100
        users := map[int]*User{key: &User{Id: 314}}
        fmt.Printf("%#v\n", users[key])

        users[key].Connected = true
        fmt.Printf("%#v\n", users[key])
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/yXaQst3py3)

---

Output:

```
&main.User{Id:314, Connected:false}
&main.User{Id:314, Connected:true}
```

Answer (score 1):

To assign a value to an item on a struct on a map in go you must make the object first.
I'll continue on your own example:

```
type User struct {
  Id int
  Connected bool
}

users[id] = User{
    Id:        id,
    Connected: true,
}
```

and if you want to assign to an existing key you should find it on your map first, like:

```
if u,ok := users[id]; ok {
    u.Connected = false
    users[id] = u
}
```